# How to hide the legend display for a specific chart?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

What I'm trying now is if I have 1 chart and then, when I click on a button with the "onchange" function, it'll display several chart. But when I'm clicking back, I have the chart I want but there is still the "legend" of the 2nd chart in the top of the 1st chart.

Is there a way to remove it ? I've found `options: { legend: { display: false }` but it remove the legend for all the chart.

Here is my code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div style="width:75%; margin: 0 auto;">
                <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-switch">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkBox" onchange="toggleCategories(event)">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="checkBox">Catégories</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


     <script>
        var test1 = [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45, 60, 43, 22, 11, 23];
        var test2 = [90, 80, 75, 62, 50, 40, 35, 11, 2, 24, 28, 34];
        var test3 = [90, 10, 90, 10, 50, 40, 23, 62, 13, 32, 11, 13];

        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                // The type of chart we want to create
                type: 'line',

                // The data for our dataset
                data: {
                    labels: ['January', 'February', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test7', 'test9', 'test10', 'test11', 'test12'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'My test1',
                        fill : false,
                        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                        data: test1,
                    }, {fill : false
                    }]
                },

                // Configuration options go here
                options: {}
            });

            function toggleCategories(e){
                if (e.target.checked) {
                  chart.data.datasets[0].label = 'My test2';
                  chart.data.datasets[0].data = test2;
                  chart.data.datasets[0].borderColor = 'rgb(255, 99, 132)';
                  chart.data.datasets[1].label = 'My test3';
                  chart.data.datasets[1].data = test3;
                  chart.data.datasets[1].borderColor = 'rgb(255, 99, 132)';
                } else {
                    chart.data.datasets[0].label = 'My test1';
                  chart.data.datasets[0].data = test1;
                  chart.data.datasets[0].borderColor = 'rgb(255, 99, 132)';
                  chart.data.datasets[1].label = '';  
                  chart.data.datasets[1].data = '';
                  chart.data.datasets[1].borderColor = '';
                }
                chart.update();
            }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Cordially

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js highly depends on its data. Therefore, the easiest way is just dynamically populating the necessary data to your chart whenever you need it. This should add and remove the legend as expected. However, don't forget updating your chart on data change.

Let's add some code to get an idea about it, since basically you're actually doing it - but just a little bit wrong.

The data of your chart is stored in `dataset`. As we can see you have 2 entries whereas the 2nd one is just an object containing a boolean property (`fill`). Therefore, it's displaying `undefined` in your legend at the very beginning.

```
datasets: [{
  label: 'My test1',
  fill: false,
  borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
  data: test1,
}, {
  fill: false
}]
```

However, when toggling the the checkbox it looks fine, since you're overwriting everything within your `toggleCategories` as seen below.

```
function toggleCategories(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    chart.data.datasets[0].label = 'My test2';
    chart.data.datasets[0].data = test2;
    chart.data.datasets[0].borderColor = 'rgb(255, 99, 132)';
    chart.data.datasets[1].label = 'My test3';
    chart.data.datasets[1].data = test3;
    chart.data.datasets[1].borderColor = 'rgb(255, 99, 132)';
  } else {
    ...
  }
  chart.update();
}
```

But taking a closer look to `else` shows what's going on here.

```
    // Those 3 lines just reset on index 1, it doesn't get deleted
    chart.data.datasets[1].label = '';
    chart.data.datasets[1].data = '';
    chart.data.datasets[1].borderColor = '';
```

So in order to get rid of the 2nd legend when you only want 1, you simply have to remove the object of `dataset[1]` and re-add it whenever you need it.

You might want to look into [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsytmajp/1/) for a fully working example:

Comment: I'm new into chart.js. What do you mean by `dynamically populating the data` ?

Comment: Updating my answer right now to be a bit more precise.

Comment: Thanks. When you say `remove the object of dataset[1]`, should I remove those 3 lines ?

Comment: You should remove the entries from your array rather then setting them to empty. You might want to look into `array.splice()` > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not really understand. The entries from my array inside my `var char` or inside my `toggleCategories` function ?

Comment: Just check the link I've added.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a solution?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div>
                <h5 id="legend" style="text-align: center;">My test 1</h5>
            </div>
            <div style="width:75%; margin: 0 auto;">
                <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-switch">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkBox" onchange="toggleCategories(event)">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="checkBox">Catégories</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


     <script>
        var test1 = [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45, 60, 43, 22, 11, 23];
        var test2 = [90, 80, 75, 62, 50, 40, 35, 11, 2, 24, 28, 34];
        var test3 = [90, 10, 90, 10, 50, 40, 23, 62, 13, 32, 11, 13];

        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                // The type of chart we want to create
                type: 'line',

                // The data for our dataset
                data: {
                    labels: ['January', 'February', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test7', 'test9', 'test10', 'test11', 'test12'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'My test1',
                        fill : false,
                        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                        data: test1,
                    }, {fill : false
                    }]
                },

                // Configuration options go here
                
                options: {legend:{display: false}}
            });

            function toggleCategories(e){
                if (e.target.checked) {
                    changeLegendOnCl();
                  chart.data.datasets[0].label = 'My test2';
                  chart.data.datasets[0].data = test2;
                  chart.data.datasets[0].borderColor = 'rgb(255, 99, 132)';
                  chart.data.datasets[1].label = 'My test3';
                  chart.data.datasets[1].data = test3;
                  chart.data.datasets[1].borderColor = 'rgb(255, 99, 132)';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("legend").innerHTML = "My test 1";
                    chart.data.datasets[0].label = 'My test1';
                  chart.data.datasets[0].data = test1;
                  chart.data.datasets[0].borderColor = 'rgb(255, 99, 132)';
                  chart.data.datasets[1].label = 'My test1';  
                  chart.data.datasets[1].data = test1;
                  chart.data.datasets[1].borderColor = 'rgb(255, 99, 132)';
                }
                chart.update();
            }
            function changeLegendOnCl(){
                  document.getElementById("legend").innerHTML = "My test 2"+"  "+"My test 3";
                }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, its this this grey rectangle that I want to hide and also the "undefined" text at the begining.